# on pdf file alignement is not good when using phantom html to pdf on node js

Tags: php, node.js, ecmascript-6, phantomjs, html-to-pdf

I'm using Phantom html to pdf module on nodejs to create pdf, converting html to pdf. when doing this pdf alignment is not good. cutting into two lines for one word on pdf file on page 1 and page 2. can any one please help me. Regards advance.

I will add screen shot then you will get an idea about it.

[image]

Comment: Can any one please help me solve this issue.

Comment: Please could any one can help me.

Comment: Were you able to fix this?